# gksu -S ask for password only once even when set to three times in sudo configuration

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, password, pam, gksu

I have a problem with `gksu` command. It always ask for password only once even when I set `Defaults passwd_tries=3` in `/etc/sudoers` file.

Command:

```
$ gksu -S --debug ls
No ask_pass set, using default!
xauth: /tmp/libgksu-h36DCX/.Xauthority
STARTUP_ID: gksu/ls/5207-0-LIFEBOOK-A532_TIME5108327
cmd[0]: /usr/bin/sudo
cmd[1]: -H
cmd[2]: -S
cmd[3]: -p
cmd[4]: GNOME_SUDO_PASS
cmd[5]: -u
cmd[6]: root
cmd[7]: --
cmd[8]: ls
buffer: -GNOME_SUDO_PASS-
brute force GNOME_SUDO_PASS ended...
Yeah, we're in...
xauth: /tmp/libgksu-h36DCX/.Xauthority
xauth_env: /home/mzajac/.Xauthority
dir: /tmp/libgksu-h36DCX
```

It does not ask for correct password again. **How can I fix it so it ask three times for correct password?**

My `sudo` configuration:

```
# sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.9p5
Configure options: --prefix=/usr -v --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-env-editor --with-editor=/usr/bin/editor --with-timeout=15 --with-password-timeout=0 --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p:  --without-lecture --with-tty-tickets --disable-root-mailer --enable-admin-flag --with-sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail --with-timedir=/var/lib/sudo --mandir=/usr/share/man --libexecdir=/usr/lib/sudo --with-sssd --with-sssd-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-selinux
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.9p5
Sudoers file grammar version 43

Sudoers path: /etc/sudoers
Authentication methods: 'pam'
Syslog facility if syslog is being used for logging: authpriv
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates successfully: notice
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates unsuccessfully: alert
Send mail if user authentication fails
Send mail if the user is not in sudoers
Use a separate timestamp for each user/tty combo
Lecture user the first time they run sudo
Require users to authenticate by default
Root may run sudo
Allow some information gathering to give useful error messages
Require fully-qualified hostnames in the sudoers file
Visudo will honor the EDITOR environment variable
Set the LOGNAME and USER environment variables
Length at which to wrap log file lines (0 for no wrap): 80
Authentication timestamp timeout: 15.0 minutes
Password prompt timeout: 0.0 minutes
Number of tries to enter a password: 3
Umask to use or 0777 to use user's: 022
Path to mail program: /usr/sbin/sendmail
Flags for mail program: -t
Address to send mail to: root
Subject line for mail messages: *** SECURITY information for %h ***
Incorrect password message: Sorry, try again.
Path to authentication timestamp dir: /var/lib/sudo
Default password prompt: [sudo] password for %p: 
Default user to run commands as: root
Value to override user's $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Path to the editor for use by visudo: /usr/bin/editor
When to require a password for 'list' pseudocommand: any
When to require a password for 'verify' pseudocommand: all
File descriptors >= 3 will be closed before executing a command
Reset the environment to a default set of variables
Environment variables to check for sanity:
    TERM
    LINGUAS
    LC_*
    LANGUAGE
    LANG
    COLORTERM
Environment variables to remove:
    RUBYOPT
    RUBYLIB
    PYTHONUSERBASE
    PYTHONINSPECT
    PYTHONPATH
    PYTHONHOME
    TMPPREFIX
    ZDOTDIR
    READNULLCMD
    NULLCMD
    FPATH
    PERL5DB
    PERL5OPT
    PERL5LIB
    PERLLIB
    PERLIO_DEBUG 
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    SHELLOPTS
    GLOBIGNORE
    PS4
    BASH_ENV
    ENV
    TERMCAP
    TERMPATH
    TERMINFO_DIRS
    TERMINFO
    _RLD*
    LD_*
    PATH_LOCALE
    NLSPATH
    HOSTALIASES
    RES_OPTIONS
    LOCALDOMAIN
    CDPATH
    IFS
Environment variables to preserve:
    XAUTHORIZATION
    XAUTHORITY
    TZ
    PS2
    PS1
    PATH
    LS_COLORS
    KRB5CCNAME
    HOSTNAME
    HOME
    DISPLAY
    COLORS
Locale to use while parsing sudoers: C
Directory in which to store input/output logs: /var/log/sudo-io
File in which to store the input/output log: %{seq}
Add an entry to the utmp/utmpx file when allocating a pty
PAM service name to use
PAM service name to use for login shells
Create a new PAM session for the command to run in
Maximum I/O log sequence number: 0

Local IP address and netmask pairs:
    10.50.52.47/255.255.252.0
    fe80::2ed4:44ff:fea2:2c4d/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::

Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.9p5
```

My `/etc/sudoers` file (I tried setting `passwd_tries=3` but removed it because it didn't work):

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults env_reset
Defaults mail_badpass
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

`/etc/pam.d/sudo` :

```
#%PAM-1.0 
auth      required  pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth      required  pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-account`:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-account - authorization settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authorization modules that define
# the central access policy for use on the system.  The default is to
# only deny service to users whose accounts are expired in /etc/shadow.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.
# 
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore] pam_unix.so 
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details. 
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth requisite pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth required pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth optional pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
auth optional pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` :

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive - session-related modules
# common to all non-interactive services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of all non-interactive sessions.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details. 
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1] pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required pam_permit.so
# The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system default in
# /etc/login.defs and user settings, solving the problem of different
# umask settings with different shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.
# See "man pam_umask".
session optional pam_umask.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required pam_unix.so 
session optional pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
# end of pam-auth-update config
```